# How to move a question from another stackexchange?

Tags: support, status-completed

I recently asked a vim question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439608/how-to-delete-a-file-from-within-a-vimscript, not realizing this stackexchange existed. Can someone move it over for me please? Thanks!

Comment: Flag the question for mod attention on the Unix site requesting it to be migrated. Or, alternatively, just delete the question there and copy/paste it to here.